# Which one to consider for accurate traffic Google Analytics or AWStats

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic, web-traffic, awstats

I have been using Google Analytics for long but i am still not convinced why Google Analytics reports less traffic than AWStats, even though i know AWStats reports traffic from bots, spiders etc..

My question is based on let us say i have two pages on website for which i want to measure traffic, so i am using both GA & AWStats

Below is the result of GA

```
PageName                 PageView
/edm/                    300       
/edm/campaign2.html      100
```

Traffic from AWStats (Pages-URL)

```
PageName                 Viewed
/edm/                    2000       
/edm/campaign2.html      400
```

Traffic reported by AWStats is almost 6 times more. so which one i should consider.

`edm` folder has two files in it one is `index.html` & other one is `campaign2.html`

If i add further details then under `Days of month` section it shows me traffic as (taken into cosideration that new page on website has been live since 15th August 18) and traffic stats which i provided are for 15th & 16th. and if you see under `Page URL section` it show page view as & below it still doesn't seem to add up as as i can understand below is for all pages not just the the two page i am looking for as accurate traffic

```
Date           Number of visits  Pages     Hits     Bandwidth
15 Aug 2018    1,311             4,727     17,974   2.72 GB
16 Aug 2018    70                178       902     178.13 MB
```

UPDATE

I would like to mention that these two page we where also tracking using bit.ly link and bit.ly stats match with AWstats which is surprising and traffic for both page on bit.ly stats show around 2,500 click on these link. So this is even creating more confusion, so did GA fail to record traffic properly

Below is the GA Analytics code which was added before the end of `Body` tag. did i do something wrong here

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxx-xx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxx-xx');
</script>
```

Comment: AWStats uses your server's logs to compile its stats, Google Analytics uses JavaScript requests. There are pluses and minuses with both. With logs, it's difficult to determine what's a bot versus an actual visit/user. With JavaScript, browsers and ad blockers can disable it, and most bots won't process it.  I'd suggest tracking changes between one versus both, so you're comparing apples with apples instead of apples with oranges.

Comment: Yes, we are comparing apple & oranges but how can i guest accurate traffic based on current stat from both.. This pages where specifically designed sms campaign so user will open these page on mobile phone only. and user are do lazy to disable JS on their phone browser... So why should i consider as best traffic guess as AWstat has 6 times more traffic for same pages ?.  So did google fail to record traffic even if JS is enabled on browser?

Comment: Sophisticated bots like Googlebot and Bingbot process JavaScript, however most others do not. So most of the difference you're seeing is likely from that. I'd consider AWStats more of a server log analyzer tool, and Google Analytics as a visitor/user analytics tool (i.e., they both have different focuses and uses). So it really depends on _what_ traffic you're interested in. If it's a campaign, I'd stick with Google Analytics. If you're interested in server management, which it appears you're not, I'd stick to AWStats.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i just want to know how well campaign went & how many time campaign pages where accessed. so based on your opinion i should consider GA which means that then my campaign pages has only 400 pageview while based on AWstat it had 2000+. SO you mean to say if i include Google bot in AWstat then still traffic should not have been so high for the same pages as compared to as Google Bot may craw website page once in 24 hours or does bot crawl same page multiple time? Just consufed

Comment: No problem. Yes, Google Analytics would likely be more representative of actual user visits and sessions, excluding ad blockers that block tracking code (which mobile devices can also use).

Comment: In regards to what you just edited in your comment: `SO you mean to say if i include Google bot in` Gooblebot is not the only bot, so no, that is not what I mean to say. There are countless bots crawling sites, some of which continously change IP's and user agents, so AWStats cannot account for those.

Comment: I would like to mention that these two page we where also tracking using bit.ly link and bit.ly stats match with AWstats which is surprising and traffic for both page on bit.ly show around 2,500 click on these link. So this is even creating more confusion

Comment: URL shorteners track all clicks/requests, so they would naturally report higher numbers than AWStats, which does account for _some_ bot traffic, but not all, so that does make sense. If you're focused on actual visitors/users, stick with Google Analytics, it's what most marketing professionals use. We've really over-reached this discussion, so hopefully you're clearer now. The question is kind of opinion-based, but I'll leave it open in case someone cares to elaborate with more specific details about the differences between the two.

Comment: @dan, i appreciate your feedback, I am myself strong advocate of GA, which i consider for correct measurement of campaign. on the other-side i will add some percentage to GA traffic as analytics may be disabled on some browser

Comment: No problem. In regards to the additional edit to your question (which is really a separate question that we get a lot here), you should `add the tracking code snippet right after the opening <head> tag on each page` - see [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en). For visitors that don't wait for your site to fully download, or if you have JavaScript that might block further loading, that can impact your stats. If you have more questions about that, please use the search above, or ask an additional question if you can't find the answer.